# Односвязный список, реализованный на массиве (С++)

Tags: c++, списки

Здравствуйте, мне дали задание, реализовать односвязный список на массиве. Я не совсем понимаю, что от меня требуется. Реализовывать стеки/деки/двусвязные и односвязные списки/очереди и т.д. умею, операции к ним тоже но с использованием структур

```
struct list {
      string val = " "; 
      list* next; 
}
```

Как должна выглядеть реализация на массиве?

Comment: Если у кого - то будут вопросы по реализации функций - пишите, я всё сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В массиве просто вместо указателя на следующий элемент используется индекс следующего элемента. Т.е. ваша структура выглядит как

```
struct list {
    string val; 
    size_t next; 
}
```

Соответственно, заголовок - просто `size_t`, равный индексу первого элемента массива, и т.д.

Например, элементы:

```
    0           1            2             3
"str1",1     "str2",3     "str4",0      "str3",2
```

образуют список из элементов массива 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2

Answer (score 1):

Предположу что имеется в виду динамический массив. То есть элементы списка хранятся фактически в массиве - непрерывной области памяти. Из-за этого вам не должны требоваться указатели на следующие элементы `next`. Должна остаться возможность добавлять и удалять элементы из любого места этого списка-массива. Что, в свою очередь, требует очень тонкой работы с динамически выделяемой памятью.